# Display None For CSS Animation

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to make an accessibility friendly website and getting hard time with implementing animation or transition with `display:none` property. I must use the `display:none` in order to it be an accessible, however it doesn't animate with the `display:none`. I remember this worked with keyframes animation, but seems like it doesn't today. Any solution, please?

**I MUST USE THE `display:none`**

Comment: There's no answer to my question. I must use the `display:none`

Comment: Animated display none IS NOT POSSIBLE you have to use opacity or something else cit from the duplicate: "CSS (or jQuery, for that matter) can't animate between display: none; and display: block;. "

Comment: @ekaterini9 You can't. The `display` property is not animatable.

Comment: But wasn't it possible once with the `keyframes`? I'm pretty sure it was. Perhaps there's another way of doing this. :(

Comment: @ekaterini9 No. You can simulate it with `opacity`, which is a spectrum of values, but `display` values are all mutually exclusive, unrelated values. The browser doesn't know how to transition between `display: block` and `display: none` as there are no in-between values.

Comment: Yes, I know about the `opacity` and `height` and other workarounds to make it almost the same, but I must use the `display:none` for accessibility. oh... hard to believe there's no way to make this

Comment: @ekaterini9 just use opacity for the animation and then on the very last step from 99% to 100% set `display: none`.

Comment: TylerH... you mean with the keyframes, right? But I tried it, and it didn't worked. Are you sure it can work with the `keyframes`?

Comment: @ekaterini9 yes https://jsfiddle.net/kz60gc7f/ it's the closest you'll get.

Comment: @TylerH Bro, the div stays in the content.

Comment: TylerH, it's because you don't apply the `display:none` to the element at the end. You apply it only as for the animation part. It's useless... set the display:none for the element and then try to animate with `display:block` from `0%`... you won't get it. At least I can't with FF, Chome and IE

Comment: BTW: jQuery won't be useful here as well(correct me if I'm wrong), because it uses the same CSS and all the rules of css apply to it as well

Comment: @K.Daniek Like I said, that's as close as you're going to get.

Comment: @TylerH Unfortunately, it's not the closest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to do it by myself with keyframes, but received an unexpected result.
Anyone can tell me why the div appears on the screen even if there's `display: none` property in the keyframe?

```css
.x {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  animation: cx 3s forwards;
}
@keyframes cx {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='x'>

</div>
```

Comment: I can :) Because you set it on the `keyframes`. You must set the `display:none` for the `.x` class as well

Comment: @ekaterini9 Then the animation won't work at all.

Comment: Exactly. That's the problem. Otherwise it's useless... because you don't actually set `display:none` to the element. What the use of this? none.

Comment: @ekaterini9 It would be fine if the keyframe would apply the `display: none` property to the element properly. I think that you should do it in JS or at least jQuery. I can do that for you if you want, with `display: none` property.

Comment: But JS uses the CSS for this... so it won't work. I will be very thankful to you if you could show me how I can make this with JS

Comment: @ekaterini9 You want pure JS or jQuery?

Comment: Pure JS will be good, but if you can't with pure JS, then jQuery

Comment: @ekaterini9 https://jsfiddle.net/syLe2oat/

Comment: Thanks Daniek! However it won't work on the backwards... It's only can be done one way. I need this as part of the accessibility where ther's a loop from - to, and backwards. But I guess this is the best it can gets. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ekaterini9 What do you mean by 'backwards'? That the div will disappear and appear infinite?

Comment: Yes. But with the `display:none` between it. It's hard to understand, but you can say that this box(in your example) will animate back(after being a display:none) and become `display:none` again, and then the animation will continue from the start(as a loop). I tried the same way with JS adding a classes and removing them(with re-checking logic, of course), but it didn't work well. Perhaps I did some mistake back there, I will check it tomorrow, but I'm almost sure I did it correctly.

Comment: @ekaterini9 I wish I could help you...